# How to pass PHP variable from a loop and use it as a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a while loop that displays some data into a table from a mysql table. Each table row has a button that is used to send data via ajax to another php page that insert the data into another table. My problem is that I want to get the values of specific rows by getting their ids but because I'm outside of the loop, I'm not able to the $row variable... How can I do such a thing?

Here is the portion of the code:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM'] . "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"billet".$row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM']."\" id=\"billet".$row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM']."\" value=\"".$row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM']."\"></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['CONCAT(Year(activites.ACTIVITY_CREATE_DTM),month(activites.ACTIVITY_CREATE_DTM))'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['CUSTOMER_NM'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['DEFAULT_WORK_GROUP_CD'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['ACTIVITY_OWNER_NM'] . "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id".$row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM']."\" id=\"id".$row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM']."\" value=\"".$row['ACTIVITY_OWNER_NM']."\"></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['groupe'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Technicien'] . "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"technicien".$row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM']."\" id=\"technicien".$row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM']."\" value=\"".$row['Technicien']."\"></td>";
        echo "<td>
                    <label for=\"date". $row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM'] ."\"><strong>Date:</strong></label>
                    <input type=\"text\" name=\"date". $row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM'] ."\" id=\"date". $row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM'] ."\" onClick=\"ds_sh(this);\" value=\"".date("Y-m-d")."\">&nbsp;
                    <label for=\"heure". $row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM'] ."\"><strong>Heure:</strong></label>
                    <input type=\"text\" class=\"timepicker\" name=\"heure". $row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM'] ."\" id=\"heure". $row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM'] ."\"></td>
                    <td><button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-block\" name=\"insert-data". $row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM'] ."\" id=\"insert-data". $row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM'] ."\" onclick=\"insertData()\">Ajouter suivi</button>
                              <br>
                            <p id=\"message\"></p>
                    </td>";
        echo "<tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<tr><td><div class=\"alert alert-dark\" role=\"alert\">Aucun r&eacute;sultat</div></td></tr>";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
<!-- Script pour envoi donnée via ajax -->
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#insert-data<?php echo $row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM']; ?>").click(function(){
    var billet=$("#billet<?php echo $row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM']; ?>").val();
    var technicien=$("#technicien<?php echo $row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM']; ?>").val();
    var id=$("#id<?php echo $row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM']; ?>").val();
    var date=$("#date<?php echo $row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM']; ?>").val();
    var heure=$("#heure<?php echo $row['TROUBLE_TICKET_NUM']; ?>").val();

// Debug
 console.log(billet, technicien, tid, date, heure);

// AJAX
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "insert-data.php",
            data: {billet:billet,technicien:technicien,id:id,date:date,heure:heure},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
             $(".message").html(data);
            $("p").addClass("alert alert-success");
            },
            error: function(err) {
            alert(err);
            }
        });

});
});

  </script>
```

Comment: Your code is basically unreadable because of the sheer amount of escaping you are manually doing, all these backslashes. This can be avoided by just _outputting html as html, instead of php_. You can easily switch out of PHP before displaying all that data, then you will have readable code, correct syntax highlighting, and you'll actually understand your code better as well as anyone else who looks at it.

Comment: Do you really hgave a column called `CONCAT(Year(activites.ACTIVITY_CREATE_DTM),month(activites.ACTIVITY_CREATE_DTM))`?

Answer (score -1):

If your intent is to allow the user to only insert values that come from existing rows, then don't pass the values you want to insert to the AJAX target. Otherwise, the user could manually call the AJAX target and simply provide any values they want. Instead, send the ID of the source row, and update the AJAX target to lookup that row and then copy the values from it.

You can do this by putting the row id into a data attribute for each row:

```
<tr data-id="<?= $row['id'] ?>">
```

Then use a jquery selector that fires on click of the button to get that value for the clicked row. Something like:

```
$(this).parent().data('id')
```

Comment: I want the user to be able to change the value of the "date" input if needed and the "heure" input.